# How should I advertise a new SE proposal?

Tags: discussion

I just started a [Soviet Union](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97056/soviet-union) SE proposal on Area 51. How should I advertise it on this site? Do I just post a question on the main board, or have to go to chat?

Comment: I think in the past meta has been used for this purpose (much like you just did here. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. I also started a chatroom but I have no idea how to invite people to it or anything else.

Comment: I am not well acquainted with how these work on Beta sites, but on the full-sties there are "Community Promotion Ads". Here is Aviation's page: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/community-promotion-ads-2016

Comment: Hm, all 5 of the proposal's example questions would be on topic on History. Why not just ask them here?

Comment: @Yannis yes I proly will. Come to think of it, that's proly as good a way as any to advertise it.